# Extending PHPUnit : adding a decorator

Tags: php, phpunit

### Context

I recently inherited the development and maintenance of a well-programmed PHP application (sarcasm). The application is based on a commercial software (which I will not name), and there is a layer of customization (ours) that is built on top of it.

Unfortunately, this application uses *a ton* of globals and singletons (pun-intended). I have built test cases for all the things we've overridden. However, a lot of things relies on some global state of something, which can cause race conditions and all sorts of weird stuff.

### Randomizing the tests

In order to catch most of these *weird-o-tons* (I like to call them that), I have built a PHPUnit `TestDecorator`, [as documented in the manual][1]. This one:

```
class PHPUnit_Extensions_Randomizer extends PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator
{
    public function __construct(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test)
    {
        $tests = $test->tests();

        $shuffle = array();
        foreach ($tests as $t) {
            if ($t instanceof PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite) {
                $shuffle = array_merge($shuffle, $t->tests());
            } else {
                $shuffle[] = $t;
            }
        }
        shuffle($shuffle);

        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite();
        foreach ($shuffle as $t) $suite->addTest($t);

        parent::__construct($suite);
    }
}
```

It basically randomizes the tests order to make sure a test doesn't depend on a global state that may or may not be correct.

### The question

The problem arose when came the time to test my custom decorator. I have not found anywhere in the manual, Google, or Stack Overflow how to load it.

When analyzing the code, I saw that PHPUnit itself was instantiating the `RepeatedTest` decorator in the `TextUI_TestRunner::doRun()` method. I know I can subclass the `TestRunner`, override `doRun()`, arrange for my decorator to be created and then just call the `parent::doRun()` with my decorator instance as the argument, override `TextUI_Command` and create a new CLI script to use my stuff instead of the built-in stuff.

Before I (re-)invent the wheel, I was just wondering, **is it possible do load a custom decorator without subclassing the TestRunner?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With current PHPUnit Versions there is no easy way to plug in in your own code for the most part. The only thing that offers interchangeability is the TestRunner and what you described makes sense to me.

I'm not aware of any other way to provide test decorators or change out most of the other classes phpunit uses.

The way you want to change the test execution order seems to work out even so I'm not sure how well it would shuffle suits.

---

Another way to achieve this thats maybe less hassle would be to create a subclass of `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` randomly `addTest` your code.

---

If that doesn't work out another option would be to use the xml configuration file and build the test suite from `<file>` tags and before every execution have some code shuffle those tags. Afaik phpunit doesn't sort them in any way so execution will be random

---

#### Are you looking to see if every tests on its on really works and want to find interdependent tests?

Or do you really want to see if something breaks horribly when you do a lot of stuff that should not change anything in the wrong order?

I'm asking just in case you haven't considered `--process-isolation` yet. (Which i assume you have but asking isn't going to hurt and might save you some time and effort :) )

When you run every test with a fresh set of globals you will at least find all test interdependencies and thats just one cli switch away to make sure every test in your suite works fine on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have considered process isolation, but it is way, way (way) to slow. I can't afford to wait 10 minutes every time I run the test suite.

Comment: @netcoder I'd suggest setting up a build that runs the suite once a night with --process-isolation to catch the odd ones and using it the normal way in day to day use. You don't want to shuffle to find randoms during the ether I'd say since you don't want your test suite to break "randomly". I've got my hands on a test suite that runs over an hour with process-isolation (yay!) and running it once a night really eased the pain of working with it.

Comment: Well since the decorator really randomizes all the tests (e.g.: order can become C::A, B::C, C::B, A::B, B::A), it doesn't really break randomly, it just breaks. As for the nightlies, it's a good idea, I'll check if I can get the IT department here to help me out. However, the issue at hand here is really to know whether you can add a decorator without overriding half of PHPUnit. Which, judging but your answer, can't be done, and I must say I find this pretty ironic.

Comment: Yeah, maybe some else has an idea how to to that nicer than creating a subclass of test runner. I was just trying to make your problem go away another way / making sure you are aware of that option :)

Comment: We also have problems with test interference--where one test alters global state in such a way as to either a) break another test or b) hide a failure in another test. I would love the ability to shuffle the tests for each run. Process isolation won't find the first type of interference.

Comment: Even though it doesn't fix my problem, I accepted this answer because it's true that PHPUnit has no facilities to add decorators. Overriding the TestRunner and Command is required to do so.

Comment: @netcoder: I've created the solution that you described in your original question in here https://github.com/fiunchinho/phpunit-randomizer, just in case you have never actually implemented it. It randomize the test cases, without modifying PHPUnit's code